# Can someone explain what this javascript (possibly angularJS) syntax means?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently learning AngularJS. This was given as an example:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
  $routeProvider 
    .when('/', { 
      controller: 'HomeController', 
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html' 
    }) 
    .otherwise({ 
      redirectTo: '/' 
    }); 
});
```

I don't understand this syntax of beginning the line with a property (i.e. `.when` or `.otherwise`. What object are these properties linked to? I'm assuming its `$routeProvider`, but two properties are being called it seems, and ive never seen properties accessed on a different line than the object. what does the entire structure of code mean? It's completely foreign to me. Is this an angularJS thing or did I learn javascript way too fast?

Comment: Obviously they're on `$routeProvider`, they're just method calls. I'm guessing your JS is minimal at best. These are simply method calls with normal parameters (a string, and two immediate objects).

Comment: in JavaScript, NewLines are just ignored whitespace ***in most cases***, so splitting this into separate lines is just done to improve readability.  This is also using [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) to execute multiple function calls in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It will call `when` method on `$routeProvider` than it will call `otherwise`  method on result of `when` call(`when` will return `$routeProvider` - it is so called [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)).

Answer (score 0):

It's basic JavaScript syntax. The `.when()` and `.otherwise()` are just function calls via property references. The fact that there are *two* of them just means that `.when()` returns an object, and probably the `$routeProvider` object itself. Thus, the return value from `.when()` can be used to invoke another method on the same object.